# Text-based web browsers era passed away?

Tags: browser

Do you think [text-based web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_web_browser) era has reached the end? Please try to enumerate your reasons by topics like CSS, Scripting, etc.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does wget and a Perl DOM parser count as a text-based browser? :)

Comment: David, please follow the link on my question. There you have a list of what I was talking about. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you define "the era of text-based web browsers".  If you define it as a period of time when more people used text-based browsers than browsers that could display graphics, then I'm not sure that era ever existed.  The first web browsers, such as NCSA Mosaic and Netscape could all display images in addition to text.  The text-only browsers came after those and provided a way for people to browse the web in environments where images were not supported (e.g. consoles/shell accounts).

However, if you define "the era of text-based web browsers" as the era in which it is possible to browse the web with text based browsers, then that era is not over.  Text-based browsers, in my experience, are a very good way to check if a site is accessible to those with disabilities (e.g. those with screen readers and the like).  As long as there are people designing sites to be accessible to everyone, text based browsers will have a role.

Comment: Good points quanticle. They still serve as testing tools. But even the most relevant books about web programming nowadays are forgetting to teach developers how to keep a website "readable" by text-based web browsers. Has authors flagged them as old fashioned?

Answer (score 0):

While they may never completely be gone, text-based browsers reached their end quite a while ago.

With the lack of support for interactive content (Flash, Silverlight, etc.), Javascript, CSS they're really just not the relevant anymore.

When the Internet was strictly about finding information, they were useful. The Web is so much more now...and text-based browsers are effectively obsolete.